# Error! 'int' object has no attribute 'append'

Tags: python

I'm very new to python and trying to write a procedure that takes a list of strings, breaks them down into their individual words, and then creates a dictionary that maps the words to each string they appear.

For example: 
makeInverseIndex(['hello world','hello','hello cat','hellolot of cats']) == {'hello': {0, 1, 2}, 'cat': {2}, 'of': {3}, 'world': {0}, 'cats': {3}, 'hellolot': {3}}

Here is my code:

def makeInverseIndex(strlist):

```
d = {}
for i in range(len(strlist)):  
    list = strlist[i].split()
    print(list)
    print(d)
    for j in range(len(list)):
        if list[j] in d:
            d[list[j]].append(i)
        else:
            d[list[j]] = i
        print(d)

return d
```

I think the problem lies with the way I am using append. I've seen some other questions like this but I can't seem to apply the answers to my code.

Comment: It is generally considered a bad idea to call a variable the same thing as a builtin (e.g. `list`).  You might consider a different name like `words` or something to that effect.

Comment: Also note that `for j in range(len(some_iterable))` can _usually_ be changed to `for item in some_iterable`.  That would really help you here as you would just change every `list[j]` to `item` which makes the code easier to read  :-)

Answer (score 7):

The problem does not lie in the way you use append. The problematic line is

```
d[list[j]] = i
```

which assigns an integer. You want

```
d[list[j]] = [i]
```

instead, which assigns a list that you can later append to.

Notice you can use [`setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) or [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) here:

```
d = {}
for i, s in enumerate(strlist):
    for c in s.split():
        d.setdefault(c, []).append(i)
return d
```

Also note that I removed all of the `range(len(..))` instances - those are necessary in C, but not in Python. Also, bear in mind `list` is a bad name for a variable, since it overshadows a [built-in](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/stdtypes.html#list).

Comment: Ah thank you very much! In your example, will the variables i, s be set to the tuples that enumerate produces?

Comment: @drunkenmonkey44 Yes, precisely, each tuple will be unpacked immediately into `i` and `s`.